# How do I write a multline problem matcher for mstest?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mstest

I created a number of failed tests across multiple files, for some good lookin' output.

```
Test run for c:\Users\anthony.mastrean.CORP\Work\gitlab.com\anthonymastrean\simplenetq\test\SimpleNetQ.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\SimpleNetQ.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
Failed   TestMethod1
Error Message:
 Assert.Fail failed. 
Stack Trace:
   at SimpleNetQ.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\Users\anthony.mastrean.CORP\Work\gitlab.com\anthonymastrean\simplenetq\test\SimpleNetQ.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 11

Failed   TestMethod2
Error Message:
 Assert.Fail failed. 
Stack Trace:
   at SimpleNetQ.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod2() in c:\Users\anthony.mastrean.CORP\Work\gitlab.com\anthonymastrean\simplenetq\test\SimpleNetQ.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 17

Failed   TestMethod1
Error Message:
 Assert.Fail failed. 
Stack Trace:
   at SimpleNetQ.Tests.UnitTest2.TestMethod1() in c:\Users\anthony.mastrean.CORP\Work\gitlab.com\anthonymastrean\simplenetq\test\SimpleNetQ.Tests\UnitTest2.cs:line 11


Total tests: 3. Passed: 0. Failed: 3. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Failed.
Test execution time: 0.5951 Seconds
```

I worked out this single-line problem matcher. But, obviously, it only matches the file and line.

```
        {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "process",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": ["test"],
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
                "severity": "error",
                "pattern": {
                    // https://regex101.com/r/SlyIHb/1
                    "regexp": "^\\s+at\\s+(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
                    "file": 2,
                    "line": 3
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Code seems to take the entire matched line as the message, by default. Let's try to do better than that. It doesn't help that mstest splits the message across two lines.

```
        {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "process",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": ["test"],
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
                "severity": "error",
                "pattern": [
                    {
                        // "regexp": "^\\s+(.*)\\s+failed\\..*$",
                        "regexp": "^Failed\\s+(.*)\\s*$",
                        "message": 1
                    },
                    {
                        // https://regex101.com/r/SlyIHb/1
                        "regexp": "^\\s+at\\s+(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
                        "file": 2,
                        "line": 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

No matter whether I match the word "Failed" before the method name or the word "failed" after the assertion, it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to help if I change the order of the pattern items.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this all evening and I found two issues:

1. From looking at examples on GitHub and the VS Code docs it seems like you need to match lines that come between the lines you want. i.e. your second pattern has `Error Message:`, `Assert.Fail failed.` and `Stack Trace:` between it and the previous pattern. Tbh I have no idea if this matters, but it "seems" to have gotten it working for me before I hit problem #2.
2. VS Code problem matcher seems to barf when the terminal wraps lines. It's hard to tell on GitHub, but it sounded like it was fixed, but I can repeatedly reproduce issues by scaling the terminal to make lines wrap and my patterns fail.

Anyway here is a problem matcher that "works" sometimes based on your original. If anyone else has feedback on this I would love to know why this is such a pain to get working. I spent like 6 hours on this getting beyond frustrated.

```json
"problemMatcher": {
    "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
    "severity": "error",
    "pattern": [
        {
            "regexp": "^\\s+(Assert.*)$",
            "message": 1
        },
        {
            "regexp": "^\\s+Stack Trace:$"
        },
        {
            "regexp": "^\\s+at\\s+(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
            "file": 2,
            "line": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if you found a better way, this question is three years old at this point, but I wanted to document this somewhere.

Some links of issues I came across that I found informative:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9635
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32042
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152634
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183262

I also logged an issue with VS Code about this and to get clarity on things:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198732